# D3 selection returns empty list; elements exist in DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm having an issue making a selection of `<circle>` elements subsequent to appending them within the containing SVG. As shown in the image they are rendered in the browser and exist within the DOM.

If `<circle>`s are directly append to SVG as the parent, D3 picks upon on the circle elements. The problem appears to be with the circles nested within the `<g>` element and that's were I get an empty selection. ***What is causing this behavior and what can be done to resolve this to get the expected result of selecting all circles?***

My repo is attached to get a full look at what I'm doing. I copied what I felt was most relevant to the question being asked?
[Project repo](http://%20https://github.com/BenLHedgepeth/d3_scatterplot_bicycle_doping/blob/main/main.js)

[image]

```
let gCircles = svg.append('g')
    .attr("transform", 
          translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})) 
    .attr("id", "circle_data");

gCircles.selectAll("circle")
    .data(response).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => xScale(years[i]))
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => yScale(times[i]))
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("fill", (d) => {
      const accusation = d.Doping.toLowerCase();
      return regex.test(accusation) ? red : blue
    });

let circles = d3.selectAll("#circle_data");
console.log(circles.selectAll("circle"));
```

Comment: The code you posted in your question will actually work! Your real problem is another one as can be seen looking at your repo. You are loading your data via `d3.json()` which is an asynchronous call returning a Promise. Although parts of your code are already dealing with that in the `then()` handler, other parts are outside of that callback and, therefore, are missing the data loaded by the async call. This question is a duplicate-in-disguise of the infamous: [*"How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"*](/q/14220321).

Answer (score -1):

You are not targetting the circles. Besides, don't use selectAll with an id. Use it with a class or a tag.

Go with

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
```